# Delete nodes/childs of another process Tree (using WinAPI)

Tags: c#, winapi, tree, treeview, ui-automation

I am trying to delete a certain child in another process Tree using Win API.

For example: There is a certain process who has a Tree. I want to delete Node3.

[image].

I am currently able to get the "index" of node3, using a TreeWalker:

```
        AutomationElement el = AutomationElement.FromHandle(--TREEHANDLE--);
        TreeWalker walker = TreeWalker.ContentViewWalker;
        int indexCounter = 0;
        for (AutomationElement child = walker.GetFirstChild(el);
            child != null;
            child = walker.GetNextSibling(child))
        {
            indexCounter++;
            if (child.Current.Name.Contains("Node3"))
            {
             //DELETE IT
            }
        }
```

I am able to view the text of all the nodes, but how can I delete a node?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no supported way to do that. If the other program offers UI to edit the tree then you can automate that UI. Otherwise it cannot be done in a safe and supported way.

UIAutomation is designed to allow automation of tasks that can be performed interactively. If you cannot do this task interactively then UIAutomation cannot help. Any attempt to delete the node by other means will be a hack relying on the implementation details of the other app. So you'll need to know precisely what control implements the tree. And there's still a good chance that deleting the node will crash the app because it may be written under the reasonable assumption that this node is never deleted.

Comment: I'm not looking for a safe and supported way to do it. The program doesn't offer a UI to do it. I thought of using SendMessage and send a n ItemDelete message to the tree, but I can't get an handle to the certain child.

Comment: It's more than likely that deleting items from the tree behind that back of the application will crash the application. If you want to hack at the control then you need to know specifically what type of control it is. For instance WinForms or WPF or Qt or FMX and so on.

Comment: Still, isn't there a way to do it? of even get an handle to the certain child tree?

Comment: The control type is WPF (Not winforms like the above picture)

Comment: The question is mutating somewhat. I feel I've given a reasonable answer to the original Q and follow-up.

Comment: Then let me explain myself again. I want to delete a child of a certain tree. I don't know if the process will crush afterwards - that's what I want to find out. In order to do so, I thought that I can use SendMessage and send a DELETEITEM message to the tree. The problem is that I don't have an handle to the tree childs.

Comment: From my perspective I'm answering the question that you asked. You did not ask about hacking WPF tree views. Note that you cannot use the SysTreeView32 messages because the WPF tree is not a SysTreeView32. You need a hack specific to WPF. Detail that was not in the question.